# completing the installation process

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I am trying to create a duel-boot Apple iMac, using Mac OS on the internal drive and Elementary on an external drive. I've gotten a bootable version on a USB thumb drive and explored the Live View, but when I look at the instructions for installing it for real, the instructions are very laking.

If this is going to be easy, and non-anxiety inducing, to do, the instructions should include screen captures of all the installation steps and/or some description of what choices you'll have for the installation.

There is no assurance that the installer will allow me to select any drive connected to the computer for installation (and avoid over-writing my internal drive.)

I've gone through the process twice and each time I've stopped when it wasn't clear that my next click was not going to erase my internal drive. The warnings to have a back up of important information just make me more suspicious that I wouldn't be able to select an external disk for installation.

This is all very simple and obvious to the developers, but not to the people who are curious to try LINUX and have no LINUX background.

Answer (score 0):

When you begin to install, in the options at the beginning, make it a custom install and then direct the installer to the drive you want to install to. You can tick or right click the other drives before installing anything to indicate they must be left unchanged then the installer will ignore those drives. It says something like DO NOT USE THIS DRIVE.
Of course you must double check that they are marked as unchanged that is not to be used for installation before you go ahead. It will tell you when you are about to install or if changes you are about to make can't be reversed.

Before installing, in the live view open "Disks" and you will be able to see how your disks are named and their sizes etc. make it easier to tell the installer which you want to install to and which should be unchanged.